# Connect heroku with Google Cloud MySql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, heroku, google-cloud-platform

I'm deploying a spring-boot backend for a react native mobile app on Heroku. Rather than using PostgreSQL in Heroku, can I know a way to connect Heroku with MySQL database which I have created in Google Cloud Platform(GCP)?

I tried to connect it with GCP using the `application.properties` file but it gives errors in Heroku.

The below code is used in application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://##.##.###.###/M######?useSSL=false

spring.datasource.username=###########

spring.datasource.password=#########
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions to [connect from an external application](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-external-app) to a Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Also, can you share the error you get? Is it a Time out? Are you using the External or the internal IP of the Cloud SQL instance?